# doxygen defgroup results in empty group

Tags: c++, doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

I have a C++ class implementation file which has some constants. The constants appear before the class method implementations. I want to group the constants together. My groups and descriptions show up in the Modules tab, but the groups are all empty. The detailed description is present but none of the group members. The groups are like this:

```
//!
//! @defgroup MY_FOOBARS list of foobar constants
//!
//! This is a more detailed description of the role
//! played by the foobar constants
//!
//! @{

static const char* FOOBAR1  = "AA";                 //!< A short summary of FOOBAR1
static const char* FOOBAR2  = "BB";                 //!< A short summary of FOOBAR2

//! @}
```

I've also tried explicitly adding the group members with @addtogroup or @ingroup, but neither seem to work.

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work and what I need to do to make it work?

**EDIT** typo pointed out by Chris

**SOLUTION**

To make this work I needed to set EXTRACT_STATIC=YES in my doxygen config.

Comment: See your answer below? You need to check mark it for it to show as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work I needed to set EXTRACT_STATIC=YES in my doxygen config. If this isn't done, the static variables in my group would not be included in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have the correct structure for you documentation (see, for example, the [member groups](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup) in the doxygen manual). However, you seem to use `//|<` for your documentation of `FOOBAR1` and `FOOBAR2`. This doesn't seem to be [valid doxygen markup](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html). Should this in fact be `//!<`?

Comment: Well spotted! I've edited that above. It hasn't helped though. I did wonder if the "after the event" comment wasn't supported for group elements and had tried putting them in front of the elements but that didn't help either.

Comment: Fixed! To make this work I needed to set EXTRACT_STATIC=YES in my doxygen config.

Comment: Great. Pherhaps you should post this as an answer and accept it.